# Memory problems in Apache with Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, apache

We are having problems with httpd memory usage with Magento.
The httpd fills up to more than 40GB in minutes and then the httpd has to be restarted.

I have this configuration. What do you think, can I solve this by changing the configuration?

```
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
  StartServers          5
  MinSpareServers       5
  MaxSpareServers      10
  ServerLimit         450
  MaxRequestWorkers   450
  MaxConnectionsPerChild   10000
</IfModule>
```

[image: System load warning]